# cpython implementation and the various built in types in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have gone through the cpython library in github. It has the source code for implementing the basic stuffs that we use in python like (dict,tuple,list, etc ie the various "types" and much more). And then I saw questions here in stackoverflow mentioning that all these 'types' are implemented as classes (which inherit from object) in the python build-ins. so that itself is the implementation right? then why do we need the cpython based implementations of the same stuffs in c programming language? PS: this might be a redundant question, i am not sure, but still a response is extremely appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you saw in the cpython source IS the implementation of builtin types. The fact that a type is implemented in C doesn't mean it's not a class and does not inherit from object - actually, the `type` (base class for all classes) and `object` class ARE implemented in C (for cpython of course - I assume they are implemented in Java for jython and in C# for ironpython). FWIW, quite a few types in the stdlib and in some 3rd part libs are also implemented in C.

As for why some types are implemented in C (or in the host language for other implementations), the answer is quite simple: performances. Python is a nice language for high level application programming but this comes at a price which is a lot of overhead and barely any room for significant optimizations, so having highly optimized C implementations of the most widely used builtin types is key to keep decent performances. This is also the case for heavy numeric computations which is why image processing (Pil / Pillow) or number crunching (numpy) python libs are mostly implemented in C. In fact, cpython has been designed from the start to make it easy to wrap C libs or write C extensions for when you need more performances (or control over memory allocation etc) than what a pure Python implementation could possibly allow.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understood now,